# Swift modules are not using localizables from L10N

Tags: objective-c, swift, localization

I'm working on a project which's been built by different modules. Most of the modules are in Objective-C, but some of them are written in Swift.

I added localizables (using L10N) in four different languages and I can see the language changes in the whole app, excepting the Swift modules.

In my project I have the `localizable.strings` files so they've been created correctly, but for some reason when I run the app, it shows my default language only.

Any idea about how this can be solved?

**EDITED:**

here is a screenshot of how localizable files are set in my project:

[image: project]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your localizable.strings added to every swift module?

Comment: Yes, I have 4 localizable files in each modules (one for each language)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your app files ? Specially the localizable ? You should have 1 Localizable, with 4 "subfiles"

Comment: ok. I edited my first message. This is how the localizables are set also in Objective-C modules

Comment: Try to remove all your strings files. Then use File / New / Strings, and Xcode will generate the appropriate file structure for you

Answer (score 0):

You will need `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` to refer strings from modules.

To get bundle you can use `+[NSBundle bundleFromClass:]`